# AWS educate account is giving client error when calling training job operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

```
estimator.fit(inputs=data_channels)
```

> ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling
>   the CreateTrainingJob operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::078087344404:assumed-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20200206T231635/SageMaker
>   is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob on resource:
>   arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:078087344404:training-job/deepar-atm-no-categories-2020-02-08-14-45-32-321
>   with an explicit deny

Comment: Please, add more context to your problem.

Comment: I am using Deep AR time series forecasting model of Amazon Sagemaker, I have AWS educate student account which has approximately $74 but , from notebook instance till connection of s3 bucket everything runs perfect but when I try to train the model it gives the client error which is mentioned above.

Comment: Did you try to google something like this? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=897879

Also, did you try to ask about this at AWS support?

Comment: Yes, I google a lot of stuff before posting it on stack overflow, well till now the question is unanswered on every link. Further AWS student Educate account cannot contact amazon for technical support

Comment: I'm not an expert in Amazon services, hopefully someone will take a look and help you, it's good that you indicated the details.
Please, edit your question with markup and instantiate where is the call and where is the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is is because your user is not able to assume role to access sagemaker, ultimately you are getting permission denied error.

FYI: SageMaker is not included in amazon educate account. You can ask your teacher/account admin to allow you to access amazon sage maker.

Comment: But in the policies section of AWS Management Console, The policy AWS Sagemaker Full access is set to my account.

Comment: Yes! May be you have full access, but if you look at the error it is saying explicit deny and that means you explicitly not allowed this service. Explicit deny denies all access no matter if you have full access policy attached to your user.

Comment: Ohh I see, Thanks a lot now I will ask from administrator to give me the access.

Answer (score 1):

At this time you cannot use SageMaker service to create a training or modeling job with an AWS Educate Starter Account.

At the present time, you can use your own personal AWS account if you'd like to use/deploy a training job with SageMaker service.

You can however continue to use Jupyter notebooks via SageMaker through AWS Educate account.